# do you always have to use "for" after the verb stay?

Tags: prepositions

are "I stayed 10 days in Algeria" and I stayed for 10 days in Algeria" both correct?

are "I stayed a month in Algeria" and I stayed for a month in Algeria" both correct?

thanks for your help

Comment: Either is acceptable, IMHO.